# JQWidgets DataTable with Detail how to update detail data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxwidgets

I'm following the example code here: [Example code](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatatable/index.htm#demos/jqxdatatable/javascript-datatable-nested-tables.htm) for nested tables. What I can't see is how to update the nested tables data when the master data rebinds to new data. Their example is somewhat opaque. Has anyone done this?